# Translating a sentence that includes HTML using CodeIgniter language class

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

How can I use HTML in language variables returned from the CI lamnguage class. To give you an example;

Normally I add tranlsated text link this:
In lang file:

```
$lang['login'] = 'Login';
```

In view:

```
<?= lang('login'); ?>
```

However some of my translated text needs to include links, for example:

```
"I agree to the <a href="" title="Terms of Use">terms of use</a>"
```

How can I translate this, the link might not appear in the same place in the sentence in different languages and my lang file will be translated by non technical staff. So i can't just dump the link HTML into the lang file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: completely agree with your comment @Alex. Here's another choise

```
$lang['terms'] = 'I agree to the Terms of Use'
$lang['terms1'] = 'Terms of Use';

$link = '<a href="your_url" title="' . $lang['terms1'] . '">' . $lang['terms1'] . '</a>';

$translated = str_replace($lang['terms1'],$link,$lang['terms']);

echo $translated;
```

Now you don't depend on phrase order. For example:

```
$lang['terms'] = 'Ados termino eta baldintzak I'
$lang['terms1'] = 'Ados termino';

$link = '<a href="your_url" title="' . $lang['terms1'] . '">' . $lang['terms1'] . '</a>';

$translated = str_replace($lang['terms1'],$link,$lang['terms']);

echo $translated;
```

Another example changing order:

```
$lang['terms'] = 'Los términos de uso son válidos'
$lang['terms1'] = 'términos de uso';

$link = '<a href="your_url" title="' . $lang['terms1'] . '">' . $lang['terms1'] . '</a>';

$translated = str_replace($lang['terms1'],$link,$lang['terms']);

echo $translated;
```

PS: I can't speak basque, so I don't know if 'Ados termino' means 'Terms of use'. Anyways, I think that you can understand how I'm trying to do.

Comment: This won't work either because the sentence structure isn't the same in all languages. For example is the Basque language it translates to: "Ados termino eta baldintzak I". In this example the link is in the middle of the sentence rather than the end.

Comment: @Alex Agree with you. I edited my own answer. I hope it helps you

Comment: Is it fine to add HTML tags and all in the 'lang_#' files? I mean some bolds and links.. Wouldn't that be hard to maintain?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the link itself is different for each language? If the link is static and the same for all the languages you can just put it in your language file

```
$lang['terms'] = 'I agree to the <a href="http://mysite.com/terms" title="Terms of Use">terms of use</a>';
```

If the link will change depending on the language, you can create the link in your controller, and the use [string formatting](http://php.net/sprintf) in your view to insert it into the language string.

So you would have this in your language files

```
$lang['terms'] = 'I agree to the <a href="%s" title="Terms of Use">terms of use</a>';
```

and in your view

```
<?php echo sprintf(lang('terms'),$link); ?>
```

where `$link` is defined in your controller and passed to the view

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, the link is the same. I want to translate the text including the link text, in this case "terms of use".

Comment: So I don't think there is any problem. Just pur the whole sentence in the language file, or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: Because the html is part of the sentence

Comment: You can put the html in the language file. There is absolutely no problem with that. You can have "I agree to the <a href="%s" title="Terms of Use">terms of use</a>" in the english file and "acepto los <a href="%s" title="Terminos">terminos</a>" in the spanish one, and anything else in other languages...